# "There is no Icenium project file in the repository" when cloning a VS+Icenium plug-in project from github

Tags: telerik, visual-studio-2013, icenium

I started a new Icenium project in VS using the Icenium Blank template, got the app working nice and then committed and sync'd it to github. Now, when I try to clone that same project inside of Mist, I get an error message:

"There is no Icenium project file in the repository"

What file isn't there that should be?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the current version of Icenium (Jan 2014) does not support interoperability between projects created in the Mist/Graphite IDEs and the Visual Studio plug-in. [From the Icenium docs](http://docs.icenium.com/creating-your-project/creating-a-new-project#create-a-new-project-in-icenium-graphite-or-mist):

> With Icenium Graphite or Mist, you cannot open, import, or modify
>   projects created with the Icenium Extension for Visual Studio.
>
> With the Icenium Extension for Visual Studio, you cannot open, import, or
>   modify projects created with Icenium Graphite or Mist.

Clearly, this is a barrier that will hopefully be eliminated soon. In the meantime, there is a blog post showing how an existing Icenium Mist/Graphite project can be manually ported to Visual Studio:

[Porting an Icenium Project to Visual Studio](http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/j-tower/2013/09/23/porting-an-icenium-project-to-visual-studio)

At the core of the problem today (I think) is that the Visual Studio integration currently leverages VS project files (for tighter integration) and does not use the same project file format as Mist/Graphite. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Todd. I'm looking forward to this feature in the future. Until then, I'll make sure that my hybrid app works in the browser so that I can collaborate with my Mac friends.